# How can I add an email signature in my iPhone Gmail app?

Tags: email, iphone, gmail

I understand it is fairly easy to add a signature to the standard iPhone mail app. However, I am now using the Gmail app on my iPhone 4S, and I can't seem to figure out how to append a signature to mail sent only through the phone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open Mobile Safari and visit [m.gmail.com](http://m.gmail.com/)
- Sign in and navigate up to the list of folders.
- There's a gear wheel in the top right, tap it.
- In here you can set your 'mobile' signature and opt to use it instead of your desktop signature.

This will now also apply to mail sent via the Gmail app.

### ***EDIT***

Theres an update to the gmail app that allows you to do the same thing but from within the app.  Show the menu by clicking the icon in the upper left of the screen and you'll see a gear wheel.  Tap that and you can set your mobile signature in there.

Comment: Awesome! This will come in handy to others.

Comment: Ok, you are right, but while replying / forwarding to mail we are not getting signature in text which was entered by me.

Answer (score 1):

I does - but it only appends emails after the entire loop rather than the current email, which is something to be fixed yet